# How to set spinner checked before opening

Tags: android, spinner

I don't know how to set checked the default item.

[image: screen]

I want to make this default item checked on start. How to do this?

```
<com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                android:id="@+id/sex"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_conten"/>

    <com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                android:id="@+id/category"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_conten"/>
```

and in class

```
            final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSex = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            SearchActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
                            listSex);

            sexS.setAdapter(adapterSex);

           final ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCategory = new ArrayAdapter<String(
                            SearchActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,
                            listCategory);

            categoryS.setAdapter(adapterCategory);
```

Comment: add your code here, no one knows which library you used, how did you add that item and etc..

Comment: post your code to get help

Comment: @ArashAfshar ok

Comment: @JimaleAbdi can u help?

Comment: @F.Fipoo look  YahiaElhattab Answers i hope it helps you.

Comment: @JimaleAbdi that doesn't work. I dont have check box.

Comment: OK try to repost your code, xml part and java

Answer (score 0):

You can type this in java:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
    checkBox.setChecked(false);
}
```

Or in XML:

```
android:checked="false"
```

Comment: I dont have checkbox in here. I just use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice.